# Node Request Library - Promise Refactoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am using the Node request library which can be found at the following link

https://github.com/request/request

I have a number of functions which look like the following

```
function doRequest() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

        request('some-url', function(error,response,body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(body)
                }
        });

    });

}
```

I then call these functions like so

```
doRequest()
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
```

My question is, is there a way of writing my doRequest function without having to create a new Promise? I feel like it is awkward looking and could possibly be an anti-pattern? Sort of how in AngularJS you often see people using

```
$q.defer()
```

when making http calls, when the http call already returns a promise.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: No, that's the right way to do it yourself and isn't an anti-pattern, although it wouldn't surprise me to find that someone already made it possible to Promisify that library.

Comment: In fact in the Git repo there are already test cases for using Promisify with `request`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Left out the reject bit for brevity!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make Promises manually based on the results of the `request()` method then that is the right way to do it (although a `reject()` call on error is also required).

However that request library already [appears to support](https://github.com/request/request/blob/8c04a23143d30a0cfef0f04236b445bfbd387689/tests/test-promise.js) the Bluebird Promise library's `Promisify` function, which can automatically wrap those functions into ones that return Promises.